# HyperLink to specific item in gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

So I am working on a basketball website. There is a gridview full of teams and what I would like is when you click on a team name, it links you to a new page that has info about the team. What I tried so far only links every team to the same details page.

Here is my gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Team" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    Height="340px" Width="776px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Team" DataNavigateUrlFields="Rank" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/MemberPages/Details.aspx?Rank={0}"
       HeaderText="Team" SortExpression="Team" ItemStyle-Width = "150" >

        <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:HyperLinkField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Rank" HeaderText="Rank" SortExpression="Rank" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PointsPerGame" HeaderText="PointsPerGame" 
            SortExpression="PointsPerGame" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OpponentPointsPerGame" 
            HeaderText="OpponentPointsPerGame" SortExpression="OpponentPointsPerGame" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TopPlayer" HeaderText="TopPlayer" 
            SortExpression="TopPlayer" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is what I tried in the cs file to databind them to a specific link:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { new DataColumn("Team"),new DataColumn("Ranking"), new DataColumn("PointsPerGame"),
        new DataColumn("OpponentPointsPerGame"), new DataColumn("TopPlayer")});

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Rank` the unique identifier for a team?  Is it static (i.e., doesn't change over time)?

Comment: @mellamokb Team is the primary key, it is meant to be a preview so it will not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that kind of show/hide logic on specific row, you will need to use [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

1. Use a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of BoundField.
2. Place HyperLink control inside.
3. Then retrieve the HyperLink control inside RowDataBound event.

### Example Code

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="MyHyperLink" Text="My Text" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(
   Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       var myHyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("MyHyperLink") as HyperLink;   

       if(SOME_LOGIC) 
       {
          myHyperLink.Visible = false;
       }
    }
}
```